# not shown infowindow in android api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

this is my code:

```
public class A_mapaAmigos extends FragmentActivity  {
    public GoogleMap mapa;
    ArrayList<Marker> marcadores;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_mapaamigos);
        mapa=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapamigos)).getMap();

        marcadores=new ArrayList<Marker>();


         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(bundle!=null)
         {
             Lugar milugar=(Lugar)bundle.getSerializable("lugar");
             LatLng pos=new LatLng(milugar.getLatitud(), milugar.getLongitud());
             Marker mimarca=AgregarMarca(pos, milugar.getNombre(), milugar.getDescripcion());
             marcadores.add(mimarca);
             CameraUpdate cu=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mimarca.getPosition(),17);
             mapa.moveCamera(cu);

         }


    }



public Marker AgregarMarca(LatLng pos, String nombre,String Descripcion)
{
    BitmapDescriptor icono= BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);
    Marker mMarcador=  mapa.addMarker(
        new MarkerOptions()
        .position(pos)
        .title(nombre)
        .snippet(Descripcion)
        .icon(icono)
    )
    ;
    mMarcador.showInfoWindow();
    return mMarcador;
}
```

only when loads the map marker is shown without any info window, told me appreciate what my mistake or is this a bug?

excuse my English, but I'm Hispanic and I'm using a translator, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Shows the info window of this marker on the map, if this marker isVisible().

```
     if( mMarcador.isVisible())
        {
            mMarcador.showInfoWindow();
        }
     else {
             Log.d(.......);
        }
```

try a simple marker and touch it to see if infoWindow appears.

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: not works for me, The problem is not that the app closes, the problem is that it does not show infowindow. thks

Comment: Info windows are designed to respond to user touch events. Are you clicking on the marker or touching it to test it ?

Comment: yes, I have implemented a mapa.setOnMarkerClickListener (listener), but still I only get markador show but not the infowindow

Comment: I mean are you physically clicking on the marker to test it ? info window only shows up when you click the marker.

Comment: not shown in any way, nor automatically or by clicking on the marker

Comment: I tried it with a marker by default and still not shown infowindow :/

Comment: lol thanks I found my mistake. The error was that the title of the marker was null due to my carelessness. Sorry to be so distracted. 

Thanks for your time.